# Sharepreference to store int value

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I have `int` value and I want it to increases by 1 when we click positive or negative button of Alert dialogue, and store the int value even when the user closes the app. I've done these but I don't know why is this not working.

```java
int counter;
```

in the oncreate

```java
initA();
```

```java
private void initA(){

if(getCounter() < 1)
{makeAlertDialogOther();}
}
```

```
private void makeAlertDialogOther() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setMessage(Constant.SETTINGS.getEntranceMsg())
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        counterU();

                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        counterU();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }
```

This is where I made sharepreference:

```java
 private void counterU() {
        sp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPrfs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        int oldCounter = sp.getInt("counterValue", 0);
        editor.putInt("counterValue", oldCounter + 1);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

```
private int getCounter() {
        sp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPrfs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sp.getInt("counterValue", 0);
    }
```

Comment: @PhanVanLinh I did that but it is not storing counter value

Comment: your should replace this `counter = counter++;` by `counter++`. it will work

Comment: @PhanVanLinh I did that too, it is still not working.

Comment: I will make a same test then let you know the result

Comment: Please tell us about the result you are getting. Clarify what you mean by **not working**.

Comment: @SamudraGanguly I mean the alertdialogue is still showing, i not able to increase the value of counter when clicking either button of alertdailogue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code not working: Whenever you close and open screen again, you start to save a new counter value (start from 0) again to your `SharedPreferences`.
The solution: Whenever we start to save a counter to `SharedPreferences`, we get the old value of counter in `SharedPreferences` first then increase and save back.

```
private void initA() {
     if(getCounter() < 1) {
        makeAlertDialogOther();
     }
}

private void makeAlertDialogOther() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
        .setMessage(Constant.SETTINGS.getEntranceMsg())
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                counterU();
            }
        })
        .setPositiveButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                counterU();
            }
        })
        .show();
}

private void counterU() {
    sp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPrfs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    int oldCounter = sp.getInt("counterValue", 0);
    editor.putInt("counterValue", oldCounter + 1);
    editor.apply();
}

private int getCounter() {
    sp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPrfs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sp.getInt("counterValue", 0);
}
```

Comment: it didn't work. I have wrapped it with this, `if (counter < Integer.parseInt(Constant.SETTINGS.getEntranceCode())) {makeAlertDialogOther()}` where `Integer.parseInt(Constant.SETTINGS.getEntranceCode())`'s value is 1. But, when I clicked later and closed the app and again opened it, the actiondialogue is still showing

Comment: oh, you mean I should replace this 'int counter = 0;` with `int counter;' in top? let me try it  again

Comment: yes, this is the problem, because this counter **always** = 0 whenever you close and open activity again

Comment: from your code I changed `int counter = sp.getInt("counterValue", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` into `counter = sp.getInt("counterValue", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` and put `int counter;` at top because i should get counter value in if condition as I commented above.

But, the alert dialogue is  still showing when I clicked later and close and again open the app.

To test It manually i put the value of counter=1; and it is not showing the alertdialogue. But i want to increase its value when clicked in cancel or update
:(

Comment: I test on my device and it working as expected. I just put 1 more Log in my code (Log.i("TAG", "counter = "+counter)), can you put it in your code and test again to see the counter can increase the value or not

Comment: I've updated my question. Can you please please check it in your by exactly those code?

Comment: before this line
`if(counter < 1)
{makeAlertDialogOther()}
}`, you need to get the `couter` value from SharedPreferences

Comment: before that line, should I keep `counterU();` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216687/discussion-between-phan-van-linh-and-madan).

Comment: can you please help me with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62531641/try-and-catch-while-retrieving-text-form-sqlite

Comment: I've updated the question, added more info. check that please.

Comment: help me with this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62887229/cant-zoom-the-webview-under-swipe-to-refresh I don't know why am I getting this